# Kill a process cleanly

Tags: process, kill

I need to make Linux Ubuntu platform automatically start and kill one process, for example, if time is 8am process starts, if time is 7pm process is killed, and that have to be every day, and should be quite okay, if time interval will be easy to change.

I'm trying to use simple codes in crontab:

```
28 12 * * * /home/pi/Desktop/start.sh
50 11 * * * pkill led.py
```

Don't look at times, I've tried to change them, `start.sh` starts `led.py` script, but I cant stop it if I'm using `pkill -9 -f led.py`. The process gets killed, but LEDs won't turn off.  If I manually start the program and then kill it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, the LEDs turn off. Where is the problem? Why I can't kill the process and at the same time turn off the LEDs?

Comment: What does the "manual kill" step, which successfully turns the LEDs off, involve?  Ctrl-C?  Another `kill`/`pkill` command?

Comment: Ctrl+C at this time, kill/pkill won't work at all

Comment: Ctrl-c sends a different signal -- try "kill -2"

Comment: `kill -2 led.py` like this?

Comment: No, `kill -2 pid`, where `pid` is the process id.  Or `pkill -2 led.py`.

Comment: `kill -2 pid` worked, but i need that in crontab, so how i can make that crontab automaticly finds `pid`?

Comment: Did `pkill -2 led.py` work?  If so, try putting that in the crontab.

Comment: Nope, `pkill -2 led.py` won't work

Comment: Please expand on "won't work".  Do you see an error message?  Is the process still running afterwards?

Comment: after `pkill -2 led.py` there is no message and process is still runnng, i can see it in htop

Comment: How about `pkill -2 -f led.py`?

Comment: `sudo pkill -2 -f led.py` worked, trying to put ir in crontab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, that usually sends the process an "INT" signal.  From [`signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html):

> ```
>   Signal     Value     Action   Comment
>   ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>   ...
>   SIGINT        2       Term    Interrupt from keyboard
> ```

It is common for processes to install a handler for this signal, allowing them to perform some cleanup before exiting.  In the case of your `led.py` script, it sounds like this handler turned off the LEDs.

By default, `pkill` and `kill` send the "TERM" (15) signal.  (You also tried sending "KILL" (9).)  These signals caused `led.py` to die less gracefully, without getting a chance to run its finishing-up function.

To allow `led.py` to finish cleanly, you should send the "INT" (2) signal, with

```
pkill -2 [process specifier]
```

The `pkill` command in your `crontab` may also have been failing to find the process, because the name you gave wasn't the one it was searching for.  From [`pkill(1)`](http://praxis.edoceo.com/man/1/pkill):

> **-f, --full**
>
> The *pattern* is normally only matched against the  process  name.
>   When **-f** is set, the full command line is used.

As your script, `led.py`, was presumably a python script, the process name was simply `python` (or `python3`, or similar).  The full command line would be something like `python led.py`, so the `-f` options lets you match on that.

```
pkill -2 -f led.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function from many years ago:

```bsh
function killit () {
for process in "$@"; do
    kill -0 $process &>/dev/null
    if [[ $? == 0 ]] ; then
        sudo kill $process #(sends a TERM, wait 5 seconds)
        sleep 5
        RUNNING=$(ps aux | tr -s " " "\t" | cut -f 2 | grep $process)
        if [[ $RUNNING ]] ; then
            echo "$0 WARNING: process $process still running, trying kill again"
            sudo kill $process #(yes, try again, wait 5 seconds)
            sleep 5
            RUNNING=$(ps aux | tr -s " " "\t" | cut -f 2 | grep $process)
            if [[ $RUNNING ]] ; then
                echo "$0 WARNING: process $process still running, trying kill -INT"
                sudo kill -INT $process  #(wait for it)
                sleep 5
                RUNNING=$(ps aux | tr -s " " "\t" | cut -f 2 | grep $process)
                if [[ $RUNNING ]] ; then
                    echo "$0 WARNING: process $process still running, trying kill -INT again"
                    sudo kill -INT $process  #(damn, still not dead?)
                    sleep 5
                    RUNNING=$(ps aux | tr -s " " "\t" | cut -f 2 | grep $process)
                    if [[ $RUNNING ]] ; then
                        echo "$0 WARNING: process $process still running, trying kill -KILL"
                        sudo kill -KILL $process #(same thing as -9)
                        sleep 5
                        RUNNING=$(ps aux | tr -s " " "\t" | cut -f 2 | grep $process)
                        if [[ $RUNNING ]] ; then
                            echo "$0 WARNING: process $process still running, trying kill -KILL again"
                            sudo kill -KILL $process #(something is wrong)
                            sleep 5
                            RUNNING=$(ps aux | tr -s " " "\t" | cut -f 2 | grep $process)
                            if [[ $RUNNING ]] ; then
                                echo "$0 WARNING: Can't kill process $process"
                                logger "$0 WARNING: Can't kill process $process"
                            fi
                        fi
                    fi
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi
done
}
```